# Run failed: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge - master

Tags: firebase, web-deployment

I'm doing firebase & react project.

However everytime I do `git push origin master` I get this email.

**

> Run failed: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge - master

**

As I click the email and it says

**

> Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge: All jobs have failed

**

Though I get this email, it still works fine. My github gets updated fine. Also if I do `firebase deploy`, my website gets updated fine. Everything works just fine but getting that email.

Is that a problem?

Answer (score 4):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy
I guess you have to read this one.
I know posting links ain't cool, but this is an official documentation and I believe it will stay up to date forever.

Or this one:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/github-integration
I am not really sure what your issue is.

I had a similar issue.
`Firebase Hosting Setup - "Set up the workflow to run a build script before every deploy? (y/n)`
I wrote `npm ci && npm run generate` and now it works.
`npm ci` is required for since your `node_modules` is missing in repo.
In my case I am using `nuxt.js` and my script is `npm run generate` instead or more common `npm run build`